# Use each value of a for loop before the loop finishes

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, setinterval

I have a function that gets values using for loops and puts them into 1 variable. This variable is them stuck in a form where its is then submitted. But the problem is that the for loop would finish looping by the time the value is entered and submitted. So everytime I test it, the variable "value" = 9999. Can anyone please tell me how to add 1 to variable every time the function loops? Thanks in advance.

```
function myFunction() {

 var value1;
 var value2;
 var value3;
 var value4;
 var value;

 for (value1 = 0; value1 < 10; value1++) {
  for (value2 = 0; value2 < 10; value2++) {
   for (value3 = 0; value3 < 10; value3++) {
    for (value4 = 0; value4 < 10; value4++) {
     value = value1.toString() + value2.toString() + value3.toString() + value4.toString() + '@2018';
     document.getElementById('pswd').value = value;
     document.getElementById('uid').value = 'test';
     document.getElementById('commentForm').submit();
    }
   }
  }
 }
}

var loop = setInterval(function() {
 myFunction(); 
}, 2000);
```

Comment: *"Can anyone please tell me how to add 1 to variable every time the function loops?"* Which variable?

Comment: Well it will submit on the first iteration of the inner loop.... not sure what you actually expect to happen...

Comment: What is your real goal here? You just want a counter?

Comment: There is a general anti-pattern in programming that if you have loops nested more than 2 deep, you are probably not thinking about the problem correctly.

Comment: Your loops are simply incrementing a number from `0` to `9999` and converting it to a string with leading zeroes. But submitting a form reloads the page, which should stop your script.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? It looks like you're trying to login to a form, trying all different 4-digit PINs.

Comment: I want to add to the "value" variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading your question correctly, you would like the number to go up by one each time the interval callback is called?  You can accomplish this by keeping track of the `value` outside the function, and do a single increment each time the callback is called.  However, you are using 4 variables to basically count from 0 to 9999.  You can simplify that a lot by using one variable to increment.  Then you can left pad it with zeroes.  That would look like this.

```
var value = 0;

function myFunction() {
    var pswd = value.toString().padStart(4, 0) + '@2018';
    document.getElementById('pswd').value = pswd;
    document.getElementById('uid').value = 'test';
    document.getElementById('commentForm').submit();

    value++;
    if(value > 9999) {
        value = 0;
    }
}

var loop = setInterval(myFunction, 2000);
```

If you can't use `padStart`, you can use `slice` instead.  You can replace that line with the following.

```
var pswd = ('0000' + value).slice(-4) + '@2018';
```